# Why can't I add a column to an existing table with a checkConstraint that references other columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alter-table, check-constraints

I'm using SQL Server and am trying to add a column and a check constraint.  I've found that the following works:

```
ALTER TABLE table.column
    ADD isTrue BIT

GO
ALTER TABLE table.column
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_table_isTrue CHECK ((isTrue = 1 AND column1 = 0 AND column2 = 0 AND column3 IS NULL) OR isTrue = 0)
```

However a less verbose way of writing this does not work:

```
ALTER TABLE table.column
    ADD isTrue BIT
    CONSTRAINT CK_table_isTrue CHECK ((isTrue = 1 AND column1 = 0 AND column2 = 0 AND column3 IS NULL) OR isTrue = 0)
```

The following error is output:

> Column CHECK constraint for column 'isTrue' references another column, table 'table'.

Looking at docs and SO I was unable to determine why this is the case

Comment: What does "does not work." mean? Do you get an error? If so what is the error?

Comment: Will edit the question above! But the error is the following: 
` Column CHECK constraint for column 'isTrue' references another column, table 'table'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not quite right.  A constraint that references multiple columns is a table constraint.  Your're trying to add a table constraint so you need a comma after the datatype definition for isTrue.

```
ALTER TABLE table.column
    ADD isTrue BIT,
    CONSTRAINT CK_table_isTrue CHECK ((isTrue = 1 AND column1 = 0 AND column2 = 0 AND column3 IS NULL) OR isTrue = 0);
```

Without the comma SQL Server thinks you're trying to add a column constraint thus the error that you're referencing a different column.